# Displaying Array Data From a File using For Loop [C++]

Tags: c++

Doing an assignment and struggling hard. I think I've narrowed down my problem to the **for loop**. Can anyone explain how to fix this? I can't find an answer on google or here that's helping me get it. I have to make an array of some data files I was given. Then use a for loop to display the results. The input is:
1/8/2016,98.550003,96.959999,70798000
1/11/2016,98.970001,98.529999,49739400
1/12/2016,100.550003,99.959999,49154200
etc.
The expected output should be clean numbers like above.
The observed output is a mess of numbers that's way too big.

```
//Variable Declaration
const int SIZE = 400;
double stockOpen[SIZE];
double stockClose[SIZE];
double stkCloseAVG=0;
double minStkClose;
double maxStkClose;
int stockVolume[SIZE];
int i = 0;
string name = "r";
string stockDate[SIZE];
string stockName;
string filename;
ifstream in;
string stkDate, stkOpen, stkClose, stkVol;
int actSize;
cout << "Welcome to " << name << "'s stock majigger thingy!" << endl;
cout << "Please enter the stock name (aapl; spy)" << endl;
cin >> stockName;
filename = stockName + ".table.csv";
in.open(filename.c_str());
if (!in)
{
    cout << "File Error! Please try again! I BELIEVE IN YOU, LOVE!" << endl;
    system("pause");
    exit(-1);
}
while (!(in.eof()) && i < SIZE)
{
    getline(in, stkDate, ',');
    getline(in, stkOpen, ',');
    getline(in, stkClose, ',');
    getline(in, stkVol, '\n');
    i++;
    // Check:cout << stkDate << endl <<endl<< stkOpen<<endl << stkClose<<endl << stkVol;
    //system("pause");
}
actSize = i;
//system("clr");
for (int i=0; i < actSize; i++) // <- Need help here
{
    cout << "Stock Daily Performance Report -" << stockName << endl;
    cout << setw(10) << "Date" << setw(7) << "Open" << setw(7) << "Close" << setw(11) << "Volume" << endl;
    cout << setw(10) << stockDate[i] << fixed << setprecision(2) << setw(7) << stockOpen[i] << setw(7) << stockClose[i] << fixed << setprecision(0) << setw(11) << stockVolume[i] << endl;
    stkCloseAVG= stkCloseAVG + stockClose[i];
    minStkClose = stockClose[1];
    maxStkClose = stockClose[1];
    if (stockClose[i] < minStkClose)
        minStkClose = stockClose[i];
    if (stockClose[i] > maxStkClose)
        maxStkClose = stockClose[i];
}
cout << "Stock Price" << endl;
cout << endl;
cout << "Average" << setw(5) << stkCloseAVG << endl;
cout << "Minimum" << setw(5) << minStkClose << endl;
cout << "Maximum" << setw(5) << maxStkClose << endl;


system("pause");
return 0;
```

Comment: Can anyone explain how to fix ***what***?

Comment: Specifically the for loop. I included all of the code because I don't know what's needed to help fix it.

Comment: What's the input, what's the expected output, what's the observed output?

Comment: The input is this long list of data in a file ( should I include that?) it's for matted like this in a notepad docuement:
1/8/2016,98.550003,96.959999,70798000
1/11/2016,98.970001,98.529999,49739400
1/12/2016,100.550003,99.959999,49154200
The expected output should be clean numbers like above.
The observed output includes gigantic numbers that are false and look like a mess.

Comment: @ReyH "Please fix my car." -> "What's wrong with your car?" -> "The engine." is not really helpful.

Comment: Cool, so instead of being a snob why don't you tell me exactly what you need to know, then? To me, it's clear. The FOR LOOP should be outputting clean data, instead it displays funky numbers. I don't know why, I've been trying to fix it.